# How do you play this notation

Tags: piano, sheet-music, sight-reading

I am studying to play a piece and it has this:
[image]

How do I play the eighth notes with the whole numbers? What does that mean?

Comment: (I'm assuming that "whole numbers" means "whole note," maybe a keyboard autocompletion mistake. If you mean something else, please edit to explain more.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that this is a piano piece, the staff is for the left hand, and that you don't have freakishly large hands.

In that case the answer is simple. The notes don't add up to a whole bar because there are two simultaneous voices notated, and the only way you can keep the organ point sounding while executing the upper voice is to use the pedal.

Comment: yes. this is a piano piece and thats for the left hand